# Looping through dictionary or list in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have this dictionary object defined.  I have put a loop together to go through and print out the KEY / VALUE pairs.

When the code loops through the "file1_info" section, I am able to access the items fine.   But, when it hits the "indexes" section, I am unable to get anywhere.

Interesting thing, if there is only 1 item under the "indexes" section, the code will work.   But more than one, I get an error.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this??

```
    DATA_INFO = {'file1_info': {
               'filename'   : 'Datafile1_' + str(yyyy),
               'file_ext'   : 'xls',
               'active'     : 'Y',
               'calc_idx'   : '1,4',
               'inc_columns': '1,2,11',
               'indexes':
                 [{'name': 'ZAXDR',   'active': 'N', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                 {'name': 'ZAXLP',   'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                 {'name': 'ZAXERNL', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                 {'name': 'ZAXERNS', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'}]
              },
             'file2_info': {
               'filename'   : 'Datafile2_' + str(yyyy),
               'file_ext'   : 'xls',
               'active'     : 'Y',
               'calc_idx'   : '1,4',
               'inc_columns': '1,2,11',
               'indexes':
                 {'name': 'ZAX', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'}
              }
            }



  for v_key, v_label in DATA_INFO.items():
    v_filename    = NYSE_INFO[v_key]['filename']
    v_file_ext    = NYSE_INFO[v_key]['file_ext']
    v_active      = NYSE_INFO[v_key]['active']
    v_calc_idx    = NYSE_INFO[v_key]['calc_idx']
    v_inc_columns = NYSE_INFO[v_key]['inc_columns']
    v_indexes     = NYSE_INFO[v_key]['indexes']

   /*** This part is not traversing the "indexes" section ***/

    for k, v in DATA_INFO[v_key]['indexes'].items():
      print("KEY: ", k)
      print("VAL: ", v)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a syntax problem in your structure at the first `indexes`. I guess it should be a list.

Comment: `DATA_INFO[v_key]` is already the `'indexes'` section if `v_key` is equal to `'indexes'`.

Comment: Ok, thank you.   So, if I change it, as I did above, like [.....], how can I look though and get key / value pairs?    I'm a bit lost, being in the middle of dictionary, and then looping though this list..........many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well there was syntax error any way you can use below loops to iterate over it.

```
for OuterKey, OuterValue in DATA_INFO.items():

    if (isinstance(OuterValue, dict)):
        print("Key :"+ OuterKey)

        for InnerKey, InnerValue in OuterValue.items():
            if isinstance(InnerValue, list):
                print("\t"+InnerKey+ " -> ")
                for eachEle in InnerValue:
                    print(eachEle)
            else:
                print("\t"+InnerKey+ " -> " +OuterValue.get(InnerKey))
    else:        
        pass
```

You can enhance further to get better result I have just iterated the structure.

NOTE: I have updated the structure as shown below.

```
DATA_INFO = {'file1_info': {
               'filename'   : 'Datafile1_' + str(yyyy),
               'file_ext'   : 'xls',
               'active'     : 'Y',
               'calc_idx'   : '1,4',
               'inc_columns': '1,2,11',
               'indexes':
                 [{'name': 'ZAXDR',   'active': 'N', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                 {'name': 'ZAXLP',   'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                 {'name': 'ZAXERNL', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                 {'name': 'ZAXERNS', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'}]
              },
             'file2_info': {
               'filename'   : 'Datafile2_' + str(yyyy),
               'file_ext'   : 'xls',
               'active'     : 'Y',
               'calc_idx'   : '1,4',
               'inc_columns': '1,2,11',
               'indexes':[
                 {'name': 'ZAX', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'}]
              }
            }
```

'indexes' ->key value is updated to list.

Comment: Danish:   This works perfectly.   Many thanks!    For the items in eachEle, is there a way to get key/value pairs?   I'll need to grab those.